# How to create a fixed div inside an another div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Dear Friends I am so struggling on about a problem came to me in my web design.
My layout as follows,

```
<div class="main_div">
<div class="left_column">
<div class=="fixed_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="mid_column"></div>
<div class=="right_column"></div>
</div>
```

and css file look like

```
    .main_div{
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    }
   .left_column{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    }
    .mid_column{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    }
    .right_column{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    }
```

What i wanted to do is i need to make the **fixed_div** fixed inside the **parent element** and give the width to 100%. But it always comes out of the left_column. How would i overcome this problem please help. Thanks
**Please note that sometimes i am changing left_column's width from jquery.So at that time the fixed_div must also adjust as the left_column.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For block elements your issue is fixed by default cos they have `width: auto;`. Do not adjust `#fixed_div` width at all and it'll work.

P.S. Using IDs for selecting all elements in `css` - isn't a good style, better rework it to the classes.

Comment: Thanks friend it solves the problem.Adjusting the `#fixed_div` gave the problem.Now it works.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
.fixed_div { 
   position: absolute; 
   left: 0; 
   top: 0; 
   width: 100%;
} 

.left_column {
   position: relative;
   float:left;
   width:20%;
}
```

Comment: I think, you understand the explanation wrong here. Please check the below post.

Answer (score 0):

You have floated all elements for this you must use clearfix technique to remove any error. And set .fixed_div to `display: block;` . If this do not help you please place a Demo. What actually you have been in problem.